# Creating an 'Insert into Post' button in plugin I am developing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, button, insert

I am developing a plugin where a user can upload a picture to an external site. I have it where it then echos the embed code so the user can just copy and paste the code right in to a post.

What I want is to create a button where the user clicks, and it then automatically adds the embed code in to the editor for a new post.

I have the button created etc. I'm not sure how to best handle this. This is the jQuery associated with the button, that currently doesn't do a thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#insertButton').click(function(){
        jQuery('#content').val(jQuery('#content').val() + 'more text');
    });
});
```

Comment: what is `#content` ,`#insertButton`? You need to post your html too.

Comment: Well, I figured #content was the 'id' of the text editor area inside of the WordPress new post screen. The #insertButton is the button I have created within my plugin, which would ideally insert text in to the text input field for the text editor

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, and I finally discovered how to do this.

Simply you create a button, where you call `insertIntoPost` JS function.

Like this:

```
<input type="button" name="send" value="Insert Into Post!" onClick="insertIntoPost('TEST');" />
```

This will close the media-library popup and insert "TEST" inside the Editor.

If it does not work, use `parent.insertIntoPost('TEST');` instead

Comment: Hm very interesting. I get an error thrown "has no method 'insertIntoPost'" the same thing also happens when I add parent.insertIntoPost